# What is there difference between SOAP, XML-RPC, JSON ?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, soap, xml-rpc

I'm sorry to ask this question but I have spent hours trying to understand where each one of them fits in in a web service. I just can't wrap my head around what do I need to use to create a web service.

I know that web service can be .Net or Java or PHP based. Say I want to create a web service in .NET using C#. When do SOAP, XML-RPC or JSON come into picture?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a very broad question and as such *may* end up being closed for not being specific enough for this site. It would be better if you reviewed the tag wiki entries for SOAP, XML-RPC and JSON and then asked more specific questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is a standard to represent human-readable data.  It merely represents data, nothing more.

SOAP is a protocol specification for transmiting information and calling web services, and uses XML to encode it.  SOAP works over HTTP (amogst other network protocols).

XML-RPC is another protocol, used for transmiting information and calling remote procedures.  It doesn't run over HTTP, but is rather a different protocol, different port, etc.

So the main difference between SOAP and XML-RPC that the former wraps inside HTTP, while the latter does not.  JSON is something completely different.

Comment: Thanks. So if I create a .NET web service in C#, I'm guessing it will use SOAP for transmitting information and XML as the data format?

Comment: That's right.  SOAP is also a well-defined standard that works across plenty of different languages, so your clients don't need to be C#, since they're basically XML files wrapped in HTTP.  I belive the same stands true for XML-RPC.

Comment: Great! Do I need to know anything about SOAP to write a web service? I saw some tutorials for creating .NET web services in Visual Studio but SOAP was never mentioned.

Comment: Nope, I've no idea to anything .NET related.  If you can't find anything helpful, another question might be the answer.